# Environment-specific initializers for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

Can you configure rails to only run an initializer under certain environments? In my case I had to hack paperclip to work with Imagemagick on my dev box, so I have monkeypatched code I want only to apply to the development environ, not the production environment. That monkeypatch is saved as a file in config\initializers.

The guides.rubyonrails.org site does not indicate that one can do this. If I can't I suppose I just won't check this patch into my repo, but that would not be ideal.

Answer (score 19):

You could put this in an `after_initialize` block in `config/environments/development.rb`, or just surround it with `if Rails.env.development?` in the initializer you already have.

I think either of these would work for you.